# Have I damaged my circuit board beyond repair?

Tags: pcb, usb, soldering

I have a USB condenser microphone which had a faulty USB port.

I purchased a new vertical female USB B Type connector and started to the process of desoldering and removing the old one from the circuit board.

When I finished, I noticed brown areas of the board and figured I probably damaged the board.

I have attached 2 photos of the piece of circuit board that attaches to the microphone’s main board. Have I ruined it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Before you start soldering the replacement back on, think a bit about what went wrong and how to prevent further damage. You must have either ripped the pad off with excessive force because the solder was not completely liquid (the connector should fall right off if desoldering is done right, if you have to pull, you're doing it wrong), or you overheated the pads so much that the resin holding the copper glued to the substrate burned up and failed. Figure out which one it was and adjust your technique accordingly. (There's some scary-looking brown residue on the other pads as well.)

Comment: It might be worth drawing up and ordering a copy of the board. This board looks simple enough that that would probably be feasible.

Comment: It's such a simple PCB and such a messy desolder job that I wouldn't even consider patching it. You could easily build a similar board by hand, out of experiment boards.

Comment: I had no idea I could order a remake, at least I thought if I could, it would probably end up costing more than the mic. I have contacted Rode to see if they can send me a replacement with the actual USB port soldered on. I'm no soldering expert, but I thought I'd give it a try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've entirely ripped two of the large pads that connect to the USB connector (one on each side of the board if I'm interpreting your photos correctly). This can be caused by excess mechanical or thermal stress.

This can be *theoretically* repaired by carefully scraping back some of the solder mask and connecting a small repair wire to the trace. However, realistically speaking, if you ripped two pads while soldering, you'd need the help of someone with more soldering experience to do such a repair.

Generally speaking, USB is fairly sensitive to wiring for signal integrity reasons. However, someone with a steady hand and decent soldering experience *may* be able to use suitably thick/thin wires and make a bypass connection similarly to the following image which would work "well enough". Note that the pinout isn't fully clear, and should be checked with a continuity test or similar. The particular pad shown here might not route to the same pin as where I drew the bodge wire.

[image]

A similar wire may need to be placed for the other damaged pad.

Because only two pads will be soldered, mechanical stability may need to be improved with hot glue or similar.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by @nanofarad, you've stripped two pads of the board in the process of removing the connector.

For the ground pad on the front of the board, this shouldn't be an issue. You can scrape off the solder mask in the area shown in orange on the below picture. Scrape using a blunt edge such as the back of a knife, or small flat head screwdriver until you see bare copper. When soldering the pin, a nice large blob of solder to the exposed region should provide connectivity and mechanical strength.

[image: Ground Pad Enlargment]

For the pad on the back of the board, this I believe is one of the data pads. To reconnect, you could either use a jumper wire to the correct pin as @nanofarad suggests (Should be as shown in lime green in image below). Alternatively, you can scrape off the area shown in orange in the picture below and again use a blob of solder to make the connection.

[image: Data Pad Connection]

---

To confirm the pinout, I am assuming you are talking about a USB 2.0 type-b socket as pictured below. If this is the case, then the pin names shown in the annotated images above are correct.

[image: USB 2.0 Type-B pinout]

<sup>[Image Source](https://www.usbgear.com/usb3-info.html)</sup>